# How to move product.info.price to product.add.to.cart for configurable products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I want to move price box on the product page to add to cart area.
I add just a line to mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart"/>
```

All work fine, but only for simple products.
[image]

On the product page with configurable product the price is disappear

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creating catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml file to mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/ for configurable product and then add below code in it.

```
<move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" />
```

Comment: Thanx, it's work!